# Computer seems completely "fried" after an unsuccessful Windows 10 update

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, windows-update, software-update

I'll try to make it short. It all started from a Windows 10 update that I have let my computer do on shutdown, I do it immediately before I leave for two days shutting my house power off, thinking that it would have made it with a full battery.

I came back and Windows wouldn't let me log in, charging on welcome screen on loop. I tried few solutions found online but none worked, I also did a reset (I had no important data locally) but with no results.

As a last resort I tried to install Elementary OS but it’d still give me errors (log follows).

```
ERROR: partitioning error: failed to commit logical partitions: unable to create volume group 'data qKzL3' on "/dev/mapper/data_qKzL3": vgcreate failed with status: 5 (Input/output error (os error 5))
ERROR: errored while installing system: failed to commit logical partitions: unable to create volume group
'data_qKzL3' on "/dev/mapper/data_qKzL3": vgcreate failed with status: 5 (Input/output error (os error 5))
INFO: Install error: failed to commit logical partitions: unable to create volume group 'data qKzL3' on "/dev/mapper/data_qKzL3": vgcreate failed with status: 5 (Input/output error (os error 5))
```

Looking at the log I repartitioned the drive, but as I remove the USB and restart the computer I would get a “No Bootable Device” on screen like nothing has been installed.

Now with this not working as well I’m caught off guard and don't know what else to do.

EDIT: follows smartctl response.

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model: SanDisk SD9SB8W256G1014
Serial Number: 19232X453215
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 4a8b38cbc
Firmware Version: X6104000
User Capacity: 256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size: 512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Form Factor: 2.5 inches
TRIM Command: Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is: Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is: ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is: SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is: Mon Aug 14 16:17:01 2023 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
 
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
 
General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status: (0x00) Offline data collection activity
was never started.
Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status: ( 0) The previous self-test routine completed
without error or no self-test has ever
been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection: ( 0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities: (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
No Auto Offline data collection support.
Suspend Offline collection upon new
command.
No Offline surface scan supported.
Self-test supported.
No Conveyance Self-test supported.
No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities: (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
power-saving mode.
Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability: (0x01) Error logging supported.
General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time: ( 2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time: ( 10) minutes.
 
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 4
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME FLAG VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE UPDATED WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 0
9 Power_On_Hours 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 5743
12 Power_Cycle_Count 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 4201
165 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 1632355487508
166 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 20
167 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 33
168 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 72
169 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 198
170 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 0
171 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 0
172 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 0
173 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 50
174 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 123
184 End-to-End_Error 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 0
187 Reported_Uncorrect 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 0
188 Command_Timeout 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 2
194 Temperature_Celsius 0x0022 075 052 --- Old_age Always - 25 (Min/Max 12/52)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 0
230 Unknown_SSD_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 8005902927688
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033 100 100 004 Pre-fail Always - 100
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 12353
234 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 100 100 --- Old_age Always - 27710
241 Total_LBAs_Written 0x0030 253 253 --- Old_age Offline - 21653
242 Total_LBAs_Read 0x0030 253 253 --- Old_age Offline - 48368
244 Unknown_Attribute 0x0032 000 100 --- Old_age Always - 0
 
SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
 
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num Test_Description Status Remaining LifeTime(hours) LBA_of_first_error
# 1 Short offline Aborted by host 00% 4888 -
 
Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Comment: Errno 5] means Input/output error. Seems like your disk has experienced a catastrophic error while you were gone. Try to get its SMART attributes by booting a Live Linux disk, and [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1804046/edit) it into your post. Question: Is your computer protected against power surges?

Comment: A catastrophic error would explain the windows update failing

Comment: Please post the S.M.A.R.T output of `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` ([smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download)). _(General FYI: an OS install or update fundamentally cannot cause hardware damage to a drive... it simply isn't possible)_

Comment: I edited the post with smartctl command response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than *install* an OS on a possibly dead drive, *test* the PC by running from a live Linux distro, such as [Ubuntu Live](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/). If that works, the PC is not "fried", though there *might* be drive issues.

Use the [Ubuntu *Disks*](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en) utility to check the drive.

- If the drive is OK, use *Disks* to remove all partitions (since you say there was no data to save),  and let Ubuntu, already running, partition the disk and install itself.
- If the drive has shuffled off this mortal coil, replace it and install an OS.

Comment: I tried once again to repartition the drive and erasing everything and let the OS install itself but nothing would change. After the _supposed_ successful installation, on restart I get "No Bootable Device" on screen.

Comment: And did you try **running from USB**, as suggested?

Comment: Yes sir, is the only way I have for running commands in a terminal.

Comment: Then you know the drive is *kaput*, but the PC is booting and running from USB. The PC is not broken, and an SSD or HDD is *easily* replaced. You can find a 250 GB SSD for ~US$15 and up. Like brakes on a car, the parts have finite life (though I've had some HDD's last ten years or more).

Comment: Well I have this computer for 7 years already so I’m okay with that, though it was the first time I’ve got into this kind of “breakage”. I guess I’m just replacing it then. Thank you for your help!